# How do I stop SQL Server swapping the month and day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2016, datetime-format

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000'; -- 1st December 2019
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

**Result**

```
2019-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

I expected the result to be `2019-12-01 00:00:00.000` (1<sup>st</sup> December 2019) - The month and the date swap for some unknown reason.

Until recently, I never had an issue with this format.

How do I enter the date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.000", and have it maintain that format once assigned to a variable/displayed in a select?
What setting determines this format that may have changed?

Potentialy useful information

```
dbcc useroptions
```

Result:

```
Set Option | Value
----------   -----
...
language   | British
dateformat | dmy
...
```

[image: Server Properties]

Things I tried:

**Query 1**

Chaning the date to something that would be invalid if swapped

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '2019-12-20 00:00:00.000';
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

Result:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

**Query 2**

Setting the variable after it's been declared

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME;
SET @someDateTime = '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000';
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

Result - UNDESIRED:

```
2019-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

Query 3

Inserting the variable into a table variable

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @someTable TABLE (someDateTimeColumn DATETIME);
INSERT @someTable VALUES (@someDateTime);
SELECT * FROM @someTable
```

Result - UNDESIRED:

```
someDateTimeColumn
------------------
2019-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

Query 4

Inserting the data directly into a table variable

```
DECLARE @someTable TABLE (someDateTimeColumn DATETIME);
INSERT @someTable VALUES ('2019-12-01 00:00:00.000');
SELECT * FROM @someTable
```

Result: UNDESIRED

```
someDateTimeColumn
------------------
2019-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

Query 5

Changing the format of the entered string

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '01/12/2019';
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

Result - DESIRED

```
2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

Query 6

Changing the format of the entered string

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '2019-12-01T00:00:00.00';
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

Result - DESIRED:

```
2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

Query 7

Changing the format of the entered string

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '2019-12-01';
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

Result - UNDESIRED:

```
2019-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

Query 8

Using `SET DATEFORMAT`

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '2019-12-01';
SELECT @someDateTime;
```

Result - DESIRED

```
2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: [`SET DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? [`convert(datetime, '20191201 00:00:00', 112)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)?

Comment: `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` does produce the desired output. But this did work previously without that. I'm unsure what has changed.

Comment: For starters, use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`. The "new" (15 year old) type has none of the old one's quirks. Second, use the full ISO8601 format, including the `T`.

Comment: @marmitegeek Apparently someone changed a server level default.

Comment: I knew `datetime` was quirky ( I knew about the date issue) but the full datetime issue is a bit unexpected

Comment: @GSerg You'd think so, but this is a local server on my work machine. Only I have access to this server. As far as I'm aware, I've not changed any server level settings.

Comment: All discussed in great detail by Tibor [here](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes). Short version - the separated format for datetime is subject to both the language setting and the dateformat setting. There are multiple formats that will always be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) article from @SMor's comment, a comment my colleague made from a google search, and remembering something I did a few months ago, I think I've worked out what's happening and what's changed.

My db user was, by default, set to:

```
language   | us_english
dateformat | mdy
```

So when reading the string `'2019-12-01'` SQL Server was expecting `mm-dd-yyyy`.

SQL server is clever though. It sees the first part `2019` and realises that it's actually the year, so it shifts the year to the end, then tries again.*

It now has `12-01-2019` which matches the format it's expecting.

When you open your account properties in SSMS, the language drop down defaults to the first language in the list (`Arabic`).
I happend to be in there a few months ago for something unrelated and decided, to make sure I didn't accidently set it to `Arabic`, I'd change that as well.

I chose `British`.

My db user is now set to:

```
language   | British
dateformat | dmy
```

So when reading the string `'2019-12-01'` SQL Server is expecting `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Once it's shifted the year, it becomes `12-01-2019` which it interprets as `dd-mm-yyyy` thus leaving me with *January 12<sup>th</sup> 2019* instead of *December 1<sup>st</sup> 2019*

Today has been a long day.

*Please note this is a rather simplified explanation of how I understand this issue. This may not be how it actually functions in reality but works to satisfy my curiosity on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the literal format `YYYYMMDD` which is always intepreted as year-month-day, regardless of the locale settings of your SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME = '20191201 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: As the OP mentions, the full ISO8601 (with the T) also works

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use the full ISO8601 format, ie `2019-12-01T00:00:00.000`, another to use the unseparated date format, ie `20191201 00:00:00.000`. A better solution though would be to switch to `datetime2`.

`datetime2` was introduced 15 (or was it 11) years ago to get rid of `datetime`'s quirks, like the millisecond inaccuracy, arbitrary precision, weird arithmetic and ... parsing idiosyncrasies. For example, `datetime2`'s parsing of the ISO8601 format isn't affected by `DATEFORMAT` :

```
SET DATEFORMAT ydm
DECLARE @someDateTime DATETIME2(0) = '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000'
select @someDateTime
------
2019-12-01 00:00:00
```

This secures your code from unfortunate server setting modifications

Comment: Didn't know about ISO8601 +1.  Learn something new every day on this site :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the catch here is that what the OP wrote is what we all think of as ISO8601 except when we don't (ie when a bug occurs). I definitely do. I didn't expect the full format to be *ambiguous* for example, just the date format. PS: I should take my advice and switch everything to `datetime2`.